# Add data-id attribute to child page links

Tags: php, menus, html, customization

The should be simple but I just can't figure it out nor find an answer.  I need to add a `data-id` attribute to the `<li>` parent container of the respective child page `<a>` links.

The HTML is as follows:

```
  <aside id="sidebar-b">
    <ul class="sub-menu side-nav page-sidebar child-pages">
      <li id="menu-item-9044" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-post current-menu-item menu-item-9044">
        <a href="http://localhost/about/" class="menu-image-title-after">
          <span class="menu-image-title">About</span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li id="menu-item-9045" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-post current-menu-item menu-item-9045">
        <a href="http://localhost/contact/" class="menu-image-title-after">
          <span class="menu-image-title">Contact</span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li id="menu-item-9046" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-post current-menu-item menu-item-9046">
        <a href="http://localhost/history/" class="menu-image-title-after">
          <span class="menu-image-title">History</span>
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </aside>
```

It should be noted that, as a temporary solution, I'm using `jQuery` to manually move the child page list out from its parent into `#sidebar-b`.

Any advice would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that your html is outputted by a wordpress menu sitting in a sidebar, you have to extend the [Walker_Nav_Menu Class](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/Walker_Nav_Menu) which is used by menu template functions like `wp_nav_menu`. As [stated in the reference of wp_nav_menu](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu#Using_a_custom_Walker_class), you could modify its output like:

```
class My_DataId_Walker_Nav_Menu extends Walker_Nav_Menu {

    //  other code found in original Walker_Nav_Menu class

    //  changing output of li elemens
    $output .= $indent  
            .  '<li id="nav-menu-item-' . $item->ID . '" '
            .  'data-id="' . $item->ID . '" ' 
            .  'class="' . $depth_class_names . ' ' . $class_names . '">';

    //  other code found in original Walker_Nav_Menu class

}

//  in the template file, output menu with custom walker class
wp_nav_menu( 
    array(
        'theme_location'    =>'primary', // your menu position
        'walker'            => new My_DataId_Walker(),
        'depth'             => 0
    ) 
);
```

Comment: Fairly certain I didn't do it the proper way but I was able to get it working. Ultimately, I copied the the `start_el` function and added `data-id="'.url_to_postid($item->url).'"` to the `$output`.

If there's a more efficient means to achieve this result I am all ears.

The menu is being outputted not from custom widget sidebar called `#top-b`.